# String '0' is true|false in javaScript

Tags: javascript, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does ('0' ? 'a' : 'b') behave different than ('0' == true ? 'a' : 'b')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496727/why-does-0-a-b-behave-different-than-0-true-a-b)

```
'0' == false; // true

'0' || 1; // '0'

'0' ? true : false; // true

!!'0' // true
```

Is `"=="` will cast `'0'`-> `0` -> `false`, but other don't?

I want more detail.

Comment: Have you made any effort to *search* for more detail? This is the subject of a million and one internet articles on JavaScript.

Comment: I attempted to Google this myself, but couldn't find any reason why `'0'` acts differently near `==`. It's a bitch Googling "=="...

Answer (score 7):

Javascript truth table for you.

```
''        ==   '0'           // false
0         ==   ''            // true
0         ==   '0'           // true
false     ==   'false'       // false
false     ==   '0'           // true
false     ==   undefined     // false
false     ==   null          // false
null      ==   undefined     // true
" \t\r\n" ==   0             // true
```

Give it a try and you will be able to remove your confusion I think.