# Inconsistency in javascript comparison operator

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why here `a = [] ? 1 : 2` a will be equal to 1 and here `b = [] == true ? 1 : 2` b will be equal to 2

Comment: The answer will be very similar to my answer here: [Why does ('0' ? 'a' : 'b') behave different than ('0' == true ? 'a' : 'b')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496727/why-does-0-a-b-behave-different-than-0-true-a-b). You just have to follow the same steps for arrays.

Comment: Because `[]` is not null and not `true` either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very similar case is handled in [Why does ('0' ? 'a' : 'b') behave different than ('0' == true ? 'a' : 'b')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496727/why-does-0-a-b-behave-different-than-0-true-a-b).

In short:

- When you have a single value that is evaluated in a boolean context, it is passed to [`ToBoolean`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) to be **converted to a boolean value**.
- If you compare values with `==` though, the algorithm in [section 11.9.3 of the ECMAScript specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) takes place. In this algorithm, both operands are **converted to either strings or numbers** and these values are compared.

---

### More detailed explanation

**`a = [] ? 1 : 2`**

The condition [is converted](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12) to a boolean by calling `ToBoolean(GetValue(lref))`. Now I assume that for objects, `GetValue` just returns the object itself and [all objects *evaluate* to **`true`**](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2).

Since arrays are just objects, the result of this expression is `1`.

**`b = [] == true ? 1 : 2`**

As already said, quite some type conversion is going on here.

First, `true` is converted to a number:

> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

[`false` is converted to `0` and `true` is converted to `1`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3).

So we have

```
[] == 1
```

Then step 9 applies:

> 9.  If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>   return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

That means `[]` is converted to a primitive value (string or number). If you follow the [`ToPrimitive` function](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) (and [section 8.12.8](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8)), you'll find out that arrays are converted to strings, by concatenating their elements with `,`.  Since an empty array as no elements, the result is an empty string.

So we end up with

```
"" == 1
```

Then step 5 applies:

> 5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

[An empty string is converted to `0`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3), hence `0 == 1` is **`false`** and the conditional operator returns `2`.

Comment: +1 A better (and more correct) explanation of what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 1):

Because an array is an object, and when an object is evaluated in the context of a boolean comparison, it is "truthy", but not exactly true.

Comment: It's not asking for exactly true, but just `==`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the array is being converted to a Boolean which yields true as it's not null, undefined, "", 0 or false.

In the second example you're getting a type conversion because of the equals operator. From mdn:

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible.

Tried the following in the console:

```
Number(true) //gives 1
Number([])   //gives 0
```

So when converted to numbers these are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

In `a = [] ? 1 : 2`, it returns `1` if `[]` is not `null` or `undefined`.

In `b = [] == true ? 1 : 2`, it would return `1` if `[]` is `true`, but it's not, so it returns `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The first is an assignment and thus has to fall through to true (but DOESN'T equate anything). Equating empty to true will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Because initialising an array with `[]` returns true and `[] == true` does not :-)