# Why would ternary ("0" ? "yes" : "no") return "yes" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

It probably was asked before but I could't find it. I read the [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12) too, didn't see anything bizzare that would explain why `"0"` evaluates to `true`.

So why would `"0" ? "yes" : "no"` return `yes`?

`("0"==true) ? "yes" : "no"` works as expected.

Comment: So you didn't see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1026459

Comment: @TravisJ No, but now that I've seen it, it still doesn't explain it to me. Under what circumstances would `"0"` evaluate to `true`?

Comment: @serg I listed the link in my answer, but this has to do with something called type coersion. You can read more about it here: http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

Comment: See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7496727/218196

Comment: It's a good question because (x) and (x==true) ought to be the same thing, but this is a case where they are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-empty strings are truthy. `"0"` is not `0`.

However, comparison will coerce `0` to a number.

Note, the only string which can be coerced to `true` *during comparison* is `"1"`. (Please let me know if there are edge cases I'm missing!)

```
"true" == true // false
"foo"  == true // false
"0"    == true // false
"1"    == true // true
```

Comment: Strings are truthy? ""? ;-)

Comment: `"0"==true` is `false`

Comment: But `!!"0"` is `true`.

Comment: That's because `Boolean("0") === true` but `"0" !== String(true)`.

Comment: Yes that because !!"0" performs a type coercion to force the statement into a true statement. This does not occur for "0" == true

Comment: Ok, the answer I was looking for is that `Boolean("0") === true`, that explains it.

Comment: @PeterOlson: `"0" !== String(true)` is not the comparison that is performed. It's `Number("0") == Number(true)`.

Comment: *"Note, the only string which can be coerced to `true` [...]"* That's not very precise. Coerced how? `Boolean("foo")` is `true` as well. If you mean "the only string (loosely) equal to the value `true`", then you are right. However, that's because both values are actually converted to numbers. The string is never converted to a boolean in that process. See my previous comment.

Comment: @FelixKling I added the qualifier "_during comparison_", but your explanation perfectly covers what I was trying to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If a string has atleast one character then the string will evaluate to truthy. As a result your first example will return "yes".

If you had used something like the following however it would have returned no:

```
"" ? "yes" : "no" // this evaluates to "no" since an empty string is considered falsey
```

This is a direct result of how type coercion occurs in javascript. I would encourage you to checkout the following link for more information on what type coercion is and how it works:  [Type Coercion](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html)

Comment: *"Your second example does not return true because type coercion does not occur."* Actually it does. In `"0" == true`, both values are coerced to numbers.